# What is the right way of checking if the user has voted or not?

Tags: php, mysql

For example, 10 results are displayed from MySQL table `products` and each product has a like and dislike button.  If the user presses like or dislike, the `voted` table is updated.

Now what i'm having trouble with is: What is the right way of checking if the user has voted or not? What to store If product has been voted with like or dislike?

If there is 300 results, I don't want to do 300 queries to check in the `voted` table if the `productid` and `userid` is present.  What would be the correct way of doing this?  I still want to show the results, just not the like or dislike button if the user has voted.

Comment: That depends on your table structure, posting the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE voted;`would help

Comment: How does `voted` look like, and how do your "300 results" look like? Which query are you trying to add user-voted check to?

Comment: voted has 3 columns (id,userid,productid).  userid and product id have a unique constraint.  The 300 results from the product table have columns(id,content) and each result has a like or dislike button.  What i'm trying to do is if the user has voted don't display the like and dislike button.

Comment: You don't have a boolean attribute for like/dislike?

Comment: accept the answer from below if you think you got your answer.. this is how stackoverflow works...

Comment: i tried to but i had to wait for a minute to expire.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Table A stores products, e.g.

```
id | product |
```

Table B stores user votes, e.g.

```
id | user_id | product_id | vote (like/dislike)
```

Then you can do a simple join query

```
SELECT `A`.`id`, `A`.`product`, `B`.`vote` from `A` LEFT JOIN `B` on `A`.`id` = `B`.`product_id` WHERE `B`.`user_id` = $current_user_id_value;
```

Then the result set will look like this

```
id |   product   |   vote   |
 1 | "product 1" |  NULL    |
 2 | "product 2" |  like    |
 3 | "product 3" |  dislike |
 4 | "product 4" |  NULL    |
...
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a [left outer join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Left_outer_join) to add the vote table rows where the user id matches the current user and the product id matches the product id from your products table to your result set.

Comment: i still want to display the result though, just not the like and dislike button.

Comment: Indeed. The result should be stored in the vote table (it would have at least three columns, e.g.: user, product and score)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest is setting a cookie for the user and the products they have voted. Of course, the user could just delete their cookies and vote again.

The consistent way would be the one you describe, saving a row for each `productId` and `userId`. No need to query multiple times, though, you'd just have to do `SELECT count(productID) WHERE productId=1 and userId=42`

You can choose, amongst different scenarios, between consistency or performance. Maybe another database engine would be the best choice, together with cookies.

Comment: The easiest is using a left join. :)

Answer (score 0):

I have an odd solution :)

1. Create a field in your product table with name `votes`, type blob (or text)
2. Save the voted user in an array like:

   `$votes = array(
        1 => true,  // userId => like/dislike (true/false)
   );`
3. Use `serialize` & `unserialize` with object `$votes` (field `vote`) to load or save voted users to you database. With less than 1 thounsand users votes on a product, the `votes` field is as small as acceptable I guess :)
4. Then you can check if the user is voted by `isset($votes[$userId])` and like or dislike by:

   `if (isset($votes[$userId]))
       if ($votes[$userId] == true) echo 'like'; else echo 'dislike';`

Because you do the checking by PHP so execute time doesn't matter.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

you can use memcache, to have the values stored with you as key=>value pair,

key can be "product_id+user_id" and when ever any change happens, update the db as well as memcache.

Comment: Memcache is not particularly needed for this. A second table does the job as well.